Logic of the java program
class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int number = 9876541, reverse = 0;
        while(number != 0){
            int remainder = number % 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("The reverse of the given number is: " + reverse);
    }
}


There is no question here, just (unformatted) code.

@ScottHunter Guestions related to software development are usually off-topic, formatted or not :-)
